# Tips on Creating Event Handler

Tags: vba, event-handling, visio

I am looking to create an event handler in Visio 2010 using VBA to have a certain segment of code occur when a shape is clicked on. There seems to be no event handler, that I can find, that fires when a shape is simply clicked once. If anyone could give me some tips, I'd really appreciate it.

An event handler is not absolutely needed, I just figured it would be the best way of going about this situation.

Thank you!

Comment: [tip1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009218/double-click-event-on-a-visio-shape), [tip2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315810(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For a single click I typically just monitor the ActiveWindow SelectionChanged event.  If the selection count is 1 then I assume that to mean the user just clicked the shape.

You can get fancy and track the selection count so that if the selection just increments by one then the last shape in the selection just got clicked.

I've not seen any shape-clicked event in Visio, otherwise.